# Using Regular Expression to set the length of a text field

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently trying to use the RegularExpression attribute to stop users form entering html tags. This does work and the error message appears. I'm now trying to get this RegEx to set a limit on the amount of characters added into the text box. This is the regex:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[^<>]{1,10}$*", ErrorMessage = "NOO")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I am quite new to RegularExpressions and dont really know the layout to how it works. I expected the values within {} would've setted the min and max length but it doesn't work, whereas checking if <> has been entered still works. How do I lay out a regular expression and what is wrong with this RegEx?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 C#.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your regex `[^<>]{1,10}$*` the asterisk behind the `$` is a bit strange, since it denotes "any number of end of lines".

When matching it against input I would interpret it as "anything that doesn't contain `<` or `>` in the last 1 to 10 characters".

If you want to limit the full length of the string you should describe everything between "start of input" and "end of input", so better add a `^` at the start of your regex:

```
^([^<>]){1,10}$
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This was close to working but not exact. Brackets were missing. This Regex worked in the end:     
       ^([^<>]){1,10}$

Answer (score 1):

```
[RegularExpression(@"([^<>]{1,10}$*)[0,30]", ErrorMessage = "NOO")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

The [0,30] defines the minimum and maximum number of characters that can be entered.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to learn all about regular expressions is here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

What is weird about your regular expression is that you have the * behind the $ sign. The $ sign indicates that you should have the end of the matching string there and the * is for repetition (0 or more). So checking for zero or more string ends might confuse things.

Beyond that, looking for 1 to 10 characters that are not < or > seems valid. So I think it's the * behind the $ that's throwing you off.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^.{6,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Name should be of minimum 6 and maximum 10 characters")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```